# How to convert these hex values to decimal in C

Tags: c, hex, decimal

I have a text file in C containing hex values in this format:

```
   F4 C3 56 78 A3
```

I want to store the decimal equivalents of these hex numbers into an unsigned char* array.

I know how to load the hex values into the array, but not how to convert them to decimal.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please show [mcve], exact input and output values.

Comment: " trying to using scanf for hours" and `“%x”` --> use regular quotes marks: `"%x"`, not smart quotes.  If this is a typo, post true code, a [mcve].

Comment: `scanf` reads from standard input `stdin` not from anywhere we want

Comment: Tip: enable all warnings.  With "(x being an int array[])" and `scanf(&buffer[i], "%x", &x[i]);`, a good compiler will warn about type mis-matches.

Comment: Each hex number takes 3 characters in your buffer, not 1. Also for strings you need `sscanf` instead of `scanf.` And you might make the array unsigned. For a start you could try this: `sscanf(&buffer[3*i], "%x", &x[i]);`

Comment: After you have removed your code, you get the mandatory comment: Please provide a MCVE. Tell us what you have, what is does and what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mix with sscanf et prinf can do the job.

```
#include <stdio.h>

bool isHexaDigit(char p) {
    return (( '0' <= p && p <= '9' ) || ( 'A' <= p && p <= 'F'));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
    char t[]="F4 C3 FF 00 78 A3";
    char* p = t;
    char val[3]; // 2 hexa digit 
    val[2] = 0;  //and the final \0 for a string
    int number; 
    
    while (isHexaDigit(*p) && isHexaDigit(*(p+1))) {
            val[0] = *p;
            val[1] = *(p+1);

            sscanf(val,"%X", &number);    // <---- Read hexa string into number
            printf("\nNum=%i",number);    // <---- Display number to decimal.
              
            p++;
            p++;
            if (!*p) break;
            p++;
      }
   return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char* txt = "F4 C3 56 78 A3";
    do
    {
        unsigned char value = strtol(txt, &txt, 16);
        printf("Value is %3u : 0x%2X\n", value, value);
    } while (*txt);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4180KB
Value is 244 : 0xF4
Value is 195 : 0xC3
Value is  86 : 0x56
Value is 120 : 0x78
Value is 163 : 0xA3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more version, it is done as the same way how we manually compute hex numbers to decimal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int hexTodec(char hexNum[]);

int main(){

    char str[] = "F4 C3 56 78 A3";
    char* hnum = NULL;
    
    printf("original num is : %s \n", str);
    
    hnum = strtok(str," ");

    while(hnum != NULL)
    {
        printf("hnum = %s ", hnum);
        printf("decNum = %d\n", hexTodec(hnum));
        hnum = strtok(NULL," ");
    }
    return 0;
}

int hexTodec(char hexNum[])
{    
    int i = 0;
    int base = 1; 
    int decNum = 0; 

    i = strlen(hexNum) - 1; 

    while( i >= 0 )
    {    
        if ( hexNum[i] >= '0' && hexNum[i] <= '9') 
        { 
            //(48)10 is ascii of 0 and (30)16
            decNum += (hexNum[i] - 48) * base;
            base = base * 16; 
        } 
        else if (hexNum[i] >= 'A' && hexNum[i] <= 'F') 
        { 
            //(A)16 is 10, but 'A' is (65)10 so, to get 10 subtract 55 
            decNum += (hexNum[i] - 55) * base;
            base = base * 16; 
        } 
        i--;
    } 
    return decNum; 
}
```